# What is dag_run.conf?

Tags: airflow

just ran into this string in a dag: 'dttm': "{{ tomorrow_ds_nodash if not dag_run.conf else dag_run.conf['calc_date'] }}"
Could somebody please help me to understand what does this string do? The main question is what are dag_run.conf and dag_run.conf['calc_date'].
Where can I read about dag_run?

Answer (score 1):

Let me start with some basics

`dag_run`: an instance of Dag execution run

`conf`: configuration dict that you can pass while executing your Dag (mostly manual execution)

`tomorrow_ds_nodash if not dag_run.conf else dag_run.conf['calc_date'] }}` means resolve the time to be `tomorrow_ds_nodash` if no calc_date configurations are passed during the execution time.

References:

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/templates-ref.html
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/dag-run.html#dag-runs